# How to create dynamic windows script that will change server ip dynamically

Tags: java, windows, windows-scripting

I have a web application in which lot of configuration files and IP address of the server is embedded in all the config files, I want that if the system IP
changes all the IP address in my config files changes automatically and no
server restart is needed. In registry we can create some bat scripts under RUN
folder, is that a good design choice, if there is some other options please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There will be a tradeoff between complexity and responsiveness.  Since IP addresses don't change frequently, and re-IPing a server usually involves downtime anyways, I would tend to err on the side of simplicity at the risk of a rare 1 minute outage

1. Use the server name and DNS lookup instead of raw IP addresses (i.e. instead of `192.268.1.10` use `myserver.mydomain.com` in your configuration files
2. set the java DNS cache time to something low (like 60 seconds), so that your JVM regularly looks at DNS for Ip addresses.  See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsJava/latest//DeveloperGuide/java-dg-jvm-ttl.html  for one of many well written "how to" articles.